# infinite Flip image using css3 3d

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to flip an image infinitely using css3, but the code is not working in firefox. Can some point me the issue.

```
<style>
    #slidecaption {
        -webkit-animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
        -ms-animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
        -o-animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
        animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
        }

        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotateY(359deg);
            -moz-transform: rotateY(359deg);
            -ms-transform: rotateY(359deg);
            -o-transform: rotateY(359deg);
            transform: rrotateY(359deg);
        }
    }
</style>

<div id="slidecaption" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000;"></div>
```

Comment: Here http://codepen.io/jjhesk/pen/lHdCA/
Search for it...you'll get many

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ObIO-SjMZc

Comment: none of them has infinite rotation.

Comment: I found a working code but the code doesnot support firefox. can someone tell me the problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here **Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/9dqAK/7/

TIP: you can increase or decrease the speed using `-webkit-animation-duration` property. Higher the delay, slower the animation.

Tested on **Firefox**. **chrome** and **IE11**.

**HTML:**

```
<img id="slidecaption" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="placeholder" />
```

**CSS**

```
#slidecaption {
   -webkit-animation-name: spinner; 
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
  animation-name: spinner; 
  animation-timing-function: linear; 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite; 
  animation-duration: 2s; 
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}


/* WebKit and Opera browsers */ 
@-webkit-keyframes spinner { 
  from 
  { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
  } 
  to { 
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-360deg); 
  } 
} 
/* all other browsers */ 
@keyframes spinner { 
   from { 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
    transform: rotateY(0deg); 
   } 
   to 
   { 
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-360deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-360deg); 
    transform: rotateY(-360deg); 

   } 
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`infinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) if you want it to "flip" contentiously.

## Basic CSS:

```
div{ 
  animation: rotation 1s infinite linear; 
}

@keyframes rotation {
  100%{ transform:rotatey(360deg) }
}
```

## DEMO:

```css
html, body{ height:100%; }
body{ perspective:1000px; overflow:hidden; }

div{ 
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0; right:0; bottom:0; left:0;
  margin: auto;
  
  background: lightblue;
  animation: rotation 1s infinite linear; 
}

@keyframes rotation {
  100%{ transform:rotatey(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

*Note* - You should also use [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)